# InvalidOperationException when creating LinearGradientBrush in multi-threaded WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, invalidoperationexception

In a `static` C# method, I do `var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(_snazzyGradient);`, and this line throws an exception.  `_snazzyGradient` is defined as follows:

```
private static readonly GradientStopCollection _snazzyGradient =
    new GradientStopCollection
    {
        new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#DBF3FF"), 0.0),
        new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#A3CCE0"), 1.0)
    };
```

The class that contains both the method and `_snazzyGradient` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if it matters, and is used as a view model.  The static method that uses `_snazzyGradient` gets called in a constructor for the class.  In a `UserControl` class, I set a dependency property's value to be a new instance of that view model class, using the constructor that references `_snazzyGradient`.

When I'm debugging my app, at the `var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(_snazzyGradient);` line, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was caught
>     Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
>     Source=WindowsBase
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
>          at System.Windows.Freezable.ReadPreamble()
>          at System.Windows.Media.GradientStopCollection.OnInheritanceContextChangedCore(EventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnInheritanceContextChanged(EventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.Freezable.AddInheritanceContext(DependencyObject context, DependencyProperty property)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProvideSelfAsInheritanceContext(DependencyObject doValue, DependencyProperty dp)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProvideSelfAsInheritanceContext(Object value, DependencyProperty dp)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
>          at System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush..ctor(GradientStopCollection gradientStopCollection)
>          at LoadedTemplate.getBackgroundForTemplateValue(String fieldName)
>          at LoadedTemplate..ctor(ParentViewModel viewModel, Template template)
>          at Form.LoadTemplate(Template template)
>     InnerException:

I've already changed the dependency property in my `UserControl` to the following:

```
public ParentViewModel Data
{
    get
    {
        return (ParentViewModel)Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate
            {
                return GetValue(DataProperty);
            },
            DataProperty
        );
    }
    set
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
            {
                SetValue(DataProperty, value);
            },
            value
        );
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I get rid of this `InvalidOperationException`?  It doesn't seem right to have to put a bunch of `Dispatcher` thread-related calls in my view model.  Should I not define `_snazzyGradient` as a static field but perhaps have it returned from a static method?  I don't know if that would help.  I definitely want multi-threadedness because I don't want the GUI bogged down when necessary files are read/written, that sort of thing.  Maybe my problem stems from using [`GradientStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientstop.aspx) (inherits from `DependencyObject`), etc. in a view model; perhaps those should be given to the view model's constructor from my `UserControl`?

Comment: Not sure if it applies here, but you should always Freeze your brushes when using them in different threads.  You'll never have to worry about threading issues when you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like moving `_snazzyGradient` from being a `static` field to a `static` method worked:

```
private static GradientStopCollection getSnazzyGradient()
{
    return new GradientStopCollection
    {
        new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#DBF3FF"), 0.0),
        new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#A3CCE0"), 1.0)
    };
}
```

It's my guess that this is because of `GradientStop` somehow, since it's a child of `DependencyObject` as is my `UserControl` class, and dependency objects have thread affinity.  Now doing `var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(getSnazzyGradient());` works fine, no thrown exception.